# How to load pdf file from local url in android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am using WebView to load the PDF.

this is my pdf from local url:

```
String pdf = "http://192.168.1.181:8081/reports/RepoActivityLog181.pdf";
```

My code:

```
webView=new WebView(MainActivity.this);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());

        String pdfURL = "http://192.168.1.181:8081/reports/RepoActivityLog181.pdf";
        webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdfURL);

        setContentView(webView);
    }

    private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                WebView view, String url) {
            return(false);
        }
```

and the output is :
No preview available

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

String pdf = "http://192.168.1.181:8081/reports/RepoActivityLog181.pdf";

```
  Thorough Intent:

   Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdf);
  Intent pdfOpenintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  pdfOpenintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  pdfOpenintent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
  try {
  startActivity(pdfOpenintent);
  }
  catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

  }
```

OR Webview

```
   WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
   webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
   webView.addView(webView.getZoomControls());
   webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview? 
  embedded=true&url="+pdf);
```

Comment: 2 one is empty,nothing is loaded in webview

Answer (score 0):

In the web view client method shouldOverrideUrlLoading, load the url and return true..

```
view.loadUrl(url);
return true;
```

Also override the onPageStarted method of the WebViewClient to see whether the url is empty or not...

```
 public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        if(url == null || url.equals(""))
            view.loadUrl("yoururl");

    }
```

Comment: again No preview Available

Comment: How many times have you tried it? Did the pdf open once? You can also override the onPageStarted Method and then check whether the url comes empty or not.

Comment: i have implement but same issue

Comment: if (url==null || url.equals("")) {
                view.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+ finalURL);
                }